# Cannot exit bash script at the end of the for cycle

Tags: bash, ping

I wrote a simple IP scanner based on ping (see below), but it has a problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter = 0

for ip in 192.168.44.{1..254}; do
  ping -c 1 -W 1 $ip | grep "64 bytes" &
  let counter++
  if [[ "$counter" -eq 254 ]];
  then
      exit 0;
  fi
done
```

First of all, the for cycle appears to be launching multiple threads and the only output to the terminal are the ping answers. However, when the script finishes pinging all the machines in the network, it never exits, as you can see in the next screenshot:

[image: Script output]

and I have to press `Enter` to finally end it.

I've also tried to place an `exit 0` after the `done` statement, but it still does not work. How can I make the script exit when the for cycle ends?

**Note:** I've found this implementation to be the fastest to find the existing machines in a LAN, but if anyone has a suggestion of a more appropriate code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Pressing Enter doesn't "end" anything; `ping` has already exited, but its output appeared after the script itself exited and overwrote the prompt. Hitting Enter simply executed a null command and displayed a new prompt.

Comment: Note that you are not launching `multiple threads`, you are launching multiple programs in the background. Your script ends before they all complete leading to the behaviour chepner describes

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So, since the script already exited, how can I display a new prompt, if there is any way to do it? Would I need to execute a new script after the previous exited?

Comment: By pressing Enter, for example.

Comment: Also, you can add `wait` before `exit` to wait for all the processes to finish.

Comment: The wait before the exit did the trick.

Comment: If you need to find machines in a LAN, have a look at the `nmap` command, which is the standard tool for network scanning. You may need to install it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want to use a dedicated network scanning tools, You can use bash or xargs to iterate over all addresses in parallel:
Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash -x

for ip in 192.168.44.{1..254}; do
  ping -c 1 -W 1 $ip | grep "64 bytes" &
done
# Wait for all children to finish
wait
```

Or with xargs, with the advantage that you can control the number of parallel addresses being pinged (20 in this example) - to avoid overloading your server with large number of concurrent process.

```
echo 192.168.44.{1..254} | xargs --max-args=1 -P20 ping -c 1 -W 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in 192.168.44.{1..254}; do
  ping -c 1 -W 1 $ip | grep "64 bytes" & 
done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> is acceptable:

```
parallel -j0 --lb ping ::: 192.168.1.{1..250}
```